# Why doesn't Rav Saadia Gaon write about wearing tefillin even during prayer?

Tags: halacha, history, tefilin, saadya-gaon

In the Siddur of Rav Saadia Gaon, he only mentions tephilin once, and even then is only talking about the bracha made when putting it on. No where does he say that when davening, you should be wearing tephilin. Nowadays it is widely accepted that you just need to have it on once a day, and preferably when you say Shema, though there are people that wear it the whole day. Why is it not mentioned?

Comment: I like your pre-edit question better for answerability reasons. Now I'm compelled to ask why you've chosen him as the focus of your question. Do you know when the practice began? Do you have other sources you've consulted to see if they mentioned it earlier or soon after his time?

Comment: I don't know when this idea started, I only focus on Rav Saadia Gaon because I was reading his Siddur and noticed this. I checked in his Sefer HaMitzvot, and there he mentions wearing "totafot litefilla".

Comment: Not just nowadays... it is an explicit gemara!

Comment: Nowadays the prevalent מנהג is not to wear תפילין all day because it is hard to keep a גוף נקי for extended periods of time, I believe.

Comment: Right, but that still doesn't explain why such an important mitzvah is not mentioned as part of the Siddur. He mentions putting on Tzitzit in the morning, but not Tefillin.

Comment: Where, in the _Sidur_, does he mention putting on _Tzitzit_ in the morning, and should have mentioned _Tefilin_ as well? (If you could also give a page number reference in the [edition available on HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/20685), it would be much appreciated.)